# Forge Viewer THREE.MeshLambertMaterial

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

One of the properties available on the `var material = NEW THREE.MeshLambertMaterial` is texture maps: `{( map: new THREE.TextureLoader().load('wool.jpg') )}`

We're very curious whether it would be possible to load in a texture this way and apply it to a specific object in the model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, but the way you modify materials in the Forge Viewer is a little bit different than what you would do in Three.js.

I have an extensive sample that illustrates how to modify materials, including custom textures here:

[Viewing.Extension.Material](https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-rcdb.nodejs/tree/master/src/client/viewer.components/Viewer.Extensions.Dynamic/Viewing.Extension.Material)

The live demo is [there](https://forge-rcdb.autodesk.io/configurator?id=59d52c493096fb09f0bfdcf2). To use it, load a model first with "Model Loader" +, then activate either "Theming color", "Material color" or "Texture" and pick a component of the loaded model. You can click in the square in each option to change color/texture.

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much. Right on the spot with this one!