# Cannot read property 'enumNodeFragments' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, 3d, autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I'm trying to change the color of elements in 3D Viewer using the Autodesk-forge platform, and for this I'm using this API https://forge.autodesk.com/cloud_and_mobile/2015/12/change-color-of-elements-with-view-and-data-api.html by Daniel Du.
But the problem is when running I got this 
[The error Pict](https://i.stack.imgur.com/enypA.png)

And this the function :

```
Autodesk.Viewing.Viewer3D.prototype.setColorMaterial = function(objectIds, color) {
        var material = addMaterial(color);

        for (var i=0; i<objectIds.length; i++) {

            var dbid = objectIds[i];

            //from dbid to node, to fragid
            viewer.addEventListener(Autodesk.Viewing.GEOMETRY_LOADED_EVENT, function () {
                var it = viewer.model.getData().instanceTree;
                console.log(it);

                it.enumNodeFragments(dbid, function (fragId) {          
                    var renderProxy = viewer.impl.getRenderProxy(viewer.model, fragId);
                    console.log("r prox : " + renderProxy);

                    renderProxy.meshProxy = new THREE.Mesh(renderProxy.geometry, renderProxy.material);

                    renderProxy.meshProxy.matrix.copy(renderProxy.matrixWorld);
                    renderProxy.meshProxy.matrixWorldNeedsUpdate = true;
                    renderProxy.meshProxy.matrixAutoUpdate = false;
                    renderProxy.meshProxy.frustumCulled = false;

                    viewer.impl.addOverlay(overlayName, renderProxy.meshProxy);
                    viewer.impl.invalidate(true);

                }, false);

            });

        }

    }
```

Hopefully, anyone has the solution to this problem...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely you are running this code before the instance tree has been loaded, which provokes the error *Cannot read property 'enumNodeFragments' of undefined* on *it* variable. You would need to wait for the [Autodesk.Viewing.OBJECT_TREE_CREATED_EVENT](http://adndevblog.typepad.com/cloud_and_mobile/2015/10/event-watcher-extension-for-view-data.html) before running that code.

Take also a look at [previous question about modifying materials in the viewer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49096901/4916074).